# Call upsell.phtml in custom phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, phtml, up-sells

I am working in the `view.phtml` file at the moment. In this file, I am using a custom .phtml file called `product.info.phtml`. I called it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

And in the local.xml I called the file like this:

```
<reference name="product.info.additional">
 <block type="core/template" template="custom/product.info.phtml" name="productInfoTabs" after="-"/>
</reference>
```

Which works just fine. In this file, I call the `upsell.phtml` file like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

But that doesn't work. If I call it in the `view.phtml`, it works. But when I call it in the `product.info.phtml` file, it fails to work.

Here is the code I am using inside the `product.info.phtml` file:

```
<dl class="product-collateral">
 <dt class="tab"><span>Test text</span></dt>
 <dd class="tab-container">
  <?php echo $_product->getInfo(); ?>
 </dd>
 <dt class="tab"><span>Test text</span></dt>
 <dd class="tab-container">
  <?php echo $_product->getService(); ?>
 </dd>
 <dt class="tab"><span>Test text</span></dt>
 <dd class="tab-container">
  <?php echo $_product->getInsurance(); ?>
 </dd>
 <dt class="tab"><span>Test text</span></dt>
 <dd class="tab-container">
  <?php echo $_product->getTerms(); ?>
 </dd>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
</dl>
```

EXTRA INFO

I did not make this myself, someone else did. I am just here to solve the bug, so there might be missing some information

Comment: How did you call your product.info.phtml file. can you share that code too?

Comment: Ofcourse, just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
            <?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_upsell')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about that... Thanks so much!

Comment: Hahaha, I will, but I couldn't at first. So I went doing something else first :p